# ANTLR4 parser rule conflict

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr4

The following is an excerpt from the file I'm trying to parse:

```
section typeSymbols:

agent, message, fact, nat, protocol_id, set

section signature:

//Super Type Declarations
message > agent         
message > nat
message > protocol_id
...

//Function Declarations
pair     : message * message -> message
crypt    : message * message -> message
inv      : message -> message
...

//Predicate Declarations
iknows   : message -> fact
contains : message * set -> fact
witness  : agent * agent * protocol_id * message  -> fact
...
```

And the rest of the file parses fine, only having trouble with the first two sections. So the rules that are supposed to handle these are:

```
//Start rule, left out the other sections because they work 
program : typesymbolssection signaturesection;

//The rules below are for handling the Type Symbols section
typesymbolssection : 'section typeSymbols:' typelist;

typelist : type (',' type)*;

type : if_type | if_operator '(' typelist ')' | '{' constantnatlist '}';
//only the first alternative should matter here.
//the rest are only used elsewhere

if_type : Const_ident;

Const_ident : [a-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*;

//The rules below are for handling the Signature Section
signaturesection : 'section signature:' signaturesection0;

signaturesection0 : supertypedeclaration* functiondeclaration* predicatedeclaration*;

supertypedeclaration : if_type '>' if_type;

functiondeclaration : if_operator ':' typestar '->' type;

predicatedeclaration : if_operator ':' typestar '->' 'fact';

typestar : type | type '*' typestar;
```

This grammar manages to parse the file correctly for the most part except for one small error. It gives the error: "no viable alternative at input 'fact'". This is referring to the first instance of fact in the Type Symbols section. It yields the following parse tree:

```
typesymbolssection
   |
   |----> "section typeSymbols:"
   |
   |----> typelist
            |
            |---> type ---> if_type ---> agent
            |---> type ---> if_type ---> message
            |---> type ---> fact //Highlighted in red because of parsing error
            |---> type ---> if_type ---> nat
            |---> type ---> if_type ---> protocol_id
            |---> type ---> if_type ---> set
```

And although I know one way to fix the error so that it parses properly, this fix introduces a much larger error. If I change

from:

```
predicatedeclaration : if_operator ':' typestar '->' 'fact';
```

to:

```
predicatedeclaration : if_operator ':' typestar '->' type;
```

then it runs without throwing any errors but it does not properly describe what I'm doing because then all of the predicate declarations are read as function declarations and it incorrectly thinks there are no predicate definitions (because at this point the definitions for functions and predicates would be the same). What makes it a predicate instead of a function is that it goes to fact. But if I clarify that by specifying in quotes that it should go to 'fact' then it trips up in the typeSymbols section. This doesn't make sense to me since they aren't even related. It figures out that it's in the type rule then gives up on the 'fact' input instead of carrying it through to Const_ident like the others.

My question is why does this make a difference and how can I correct this so that I can avoid both errors? I don't understand why changing from "type" to " 'fact' " should make a difference in the first section. So far I'm stuck where I have one error or the other and I've been banging my head against this for three days. Any help massively appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issues with ordering (thus precedence of) your rules.
First lexer rule that can match will match.

```
Const_ident : [a-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*; // will match the token 'fact'!

//...

predicatedeclaration : if_operator ':' typestar '->' 'fact'; // implicitly creates the token 'fact', which will NEVER match since it's always matched by Const_ident rule!
```

Try something like this:

```
predicatedeclaration : if_operator ':' typestar '->' Fact ;


Fact : 'fact'; // now 'fact' will be a Fact not a Const_ident
Const_ident : [a-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*;
```

Check also for similar other cases in your grammar.

Advice:

- Put all lexer rules in one place, so you'll clearly see the precedence. Put the most specialized first, so they'll "win" over the more general rules.
- Don't use implicit tokens (i.e. 'something' in your parser rules)
- It's best to even separate parser and lexer grammars into two files. This disallows creation of implicit tokens.

EDIT:

If `fact` shall sometimes be a `Fact` and sometimes a 'Const_ident', you can use the following approach:

```
// use parser rules for `Const_ident` now. I.e. in all parser rules only use the parser rule, not the token directly.
const_ident  : Const_ident | Fact; // will match `Const_ident`s and `fact`s


Fact : 'fact';
Const_ident : [a-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*; // don't use this directly in parser rules but `const_ident` instead!
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the problem for me. I've tried the rules in multiple orders already but still run into an issue. Also, I believe I read in the ANTLR4 reference book that the lexer will take the first LONGEST production (meaning it will pick whichever consumes the most characters, and, given a tie, it will pick the one that came first). The problem is that the string fact appears twice in the input and I want it to be treated differently each time.

Comment: But a "fact" can always be matched by "Const_ident" and thus will always by this rule if it comes first.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to say. I tried it and it didn't fix the problem. The problem is that the first time 'fact' shows up in the input, it needs to be a Const_ident, every time after, it needs to be a Fact. Right now, my best solution is to preprocess around the problem by adding stuff to the input file to make functions and predicates differently formed...

Comment: @user3380049: See the EDIT part of my answer